# SparkR lapply not working

Tags: r, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, sparkr

I am trying to run a simple lapply over a column on a DataFrame using SparkR and it is giving me an error. My code is as follows:

```
ff <- sql(sqlContext, "SELECT `device`.`browser`.`cookie` FROM transactionsTbl")
showDF(ff)
```

and the output is:

```
+--------------------+
|          cookie-_cc|
+--------------------+
|ZWYyNDc5NmMtZjBjN...|
|ZTU4YjhmNTYtYjI3Z...|
|YjQwNDRlNjMtNTZjZ...|
|NzNlMDFkMTQtZTBjY...|
|MjQ2NTg1ZmYtNzFiN...|
|ZWIyMzY2NGUtMmI3M...|
```

Now when I try to run the simple lapply:

```
ffl <- lapply(ff$'cookie',length)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in as.list.default(X) : 
  no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector
```

I want to keep the data structure as a DataFrame and not a data.frame so I won't lose Spark's benefits. Please help!! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

SparkR `DataFrames` are not compatible with standard R API. To access and transform these you should use SparkR DSL or SQL expressions. To find a length of the string you can use `length` function

```
df <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, iris)
select(df, length(df$Species))
```